# Bad Request. INTERNAL SERVICE ERROR on pgadmin4 on docker

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I installed pgadmin4 and postgres on my VPS successfully, but I got this error. I could not found the solution on internet either. What is the cause of the error, and how can the problem be fixed?

Installing instruction: https://github.com/khezen/compose-postgres/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

The error dialog just says "Bad Request", and I get a notification at the bottom right in red that there was an "INTERNAL SERVICE ERROR".

[Here's a screenshot so you can see what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBzGg.png).